# Should application version be stored in source control (e.g. Git) or CI?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, versioning

We're migrating from locally run build/deploy scripts to a CI server. As of now, we keep the application version (C# AssemblyInfo.cs), which works decently.

I was wondering if there were any advantages/disadvantages of keeping the version inside our CI system rather than Git. I am unable to find much information on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work in a team which has multiple modules . I would prefer you store your version number in the CI system and tag your versioned code in Git .

The reason is that if you store your version in , say a file system. It becomes problematic over a period of time to increment it and share it across different modules. The overhead is not justified especially when versioning and auto incrementing solutions come out of the box with many build/ CI systems.